# How to connect your react ethereum project with MetaMask wallet?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, react

I am developing a ReactJs blockchain application on ethereum network. How can I use MetaMask Wallet instead of local ganache account.

```
import web3 from 'Web3';
const web3 = new Web3("localurl");
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this guide](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check). To summarize: first check whether web3 already exists. If it does, initialize a Web3 object with web3.currentProvider. Otherwise, use your node's URL

Comment: In react environment, what **web3.currentProvider**  will refer to as web3 is still not instantiated.

Comment: If MetaMask is installed and working, web3 will be instantiated. If MetaMask is not installed, web3 will be `undefined` and you have to instantiate it yourself

Answer (score -1):

```
var web3 = new Web3();
    if (window.ethereum) {
      web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      try {
        window.ethereum.enable().then(function() {
          // User has allowed account access to DApp...
        });
      } catch (e) {
        // User has denied account access to DApp...
      }
    }
    // Legacy DApp Browsers
    else if (window.web3) {
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    }
    // Non-DApp Browsers
    else {
      alert("You have to install MetaMask !");
    }
    window.ethereum.enable();
    console.log(" typoe of = ", typeof web3);
    if (typeof web3 != "undefined") {
      this.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      window.ethereum.enable();
    } else {
      this.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
      );
      window.ethereum.enable();
    }
```